# how the recursion works in this code?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
// interleaving of two string

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

bool isinterleav(string & a, string & b, string & c, int i, int j, int k) {

    if(i == -1 && k == -1 && j == -1) return true;

    bool x = false, y = false ;
    if(a[i] == c[k]) x = isinterleav(a,b,c,i-1,j,k-1);
     //cout <<  x <<" " <<  y << " " << i << " " << j << " " << k <<   endl;
    if(b[j] == c[k]) y = isinterleav(a,b,c,i,j-1,k-1);
    return x || y;
}

int main() {

    string a = "AFGHA", b = "ABCDA", c = "AFGHAABCDA";
    int i, j, k;
    //cin >> a >> b >> c;

    i = a.length()-1;
    j = b.length()-1;
    k = c.length()-1;

    if(isinterleav(a,b,c,i,j,k))
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else cout << "No" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the point at your question? Be more specific. In my opinion, any part of this code is not written by you. Candidate for hold.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: actually i did not understand that how is isinterleav() function work in this code

Comment: recursion is like winding and unwinding for example when we calculate factorial of n by recursion then first it return of 1! then it return 2! and so on it finally return n! in that way how the code return true value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my thought, hope it will help:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isinterleav(string & a, string & b, string & c, int i, int j, int k) {
if(i == -1 && k == -1 && j == -1) return true;

bool x = false, y = false ;
if(a[i] == c[k]) x = isinterleav(a,b,c,i-1,j,k-1);
//cout <<  x <<" " <<  y << " " << i << " " << j << " " << k <<   endl;
/*it will inspect the next i and k till can't inspect anymore
In your case: i=-1,k=5,x=false that you set before ;*/
if(b[j] == c[k]) y = isinterleav(a,b,c,i,j-1,k-1);
 /* and it will continue doing this with j and k with k=5 till can't inspect anymore 
 In your case j=-1,k=-1,i=-1 =>y=true  */
 return x || y; //and your case is True||false => True

 }
 int main() {

 string a = "AFGHA", b = "ABCDA", c = "AFGHAABCDA";
 int i, j, k;
 //cin >> a >> b >> c;

 i = a.length()-1;
 j = b.length()-1;
 k = c.length()-1;

 if(isinterleav(a,b,c,i,j,k))
   cout << "Yes" << endl;
  else cout << "No" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: recursion is like winding and unwinding for example when we calculate factorial of n by recursion then first it return of 1! then it return 2! and so on it finally return n! in that way how the code return true value

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to understand what the code is doing. The program is checking if the string C is a combination of String A and String B, interleaved together.

The recursive method is comparing the strings from the end and checking if the the current end character is same as the current end character in a or current end character in b. if the character is same in the either combination, it advances the index to check the next character from the end.

The recursion terminates with true if C is a perfect interleave of A and B. Otherwise terminates with false.

Hope this helps.